# Print out hyperlink in Jenkins console output using Python

Tags: python, jenkins, hyperlink, jenkins-plugins

I am triggering a python script through a Jenkins job, and would print a hyperlink in the Jenkins console output. Is there a Jenkins plugin or python module I can use to achieve this.

From a test script, I tried doing this - echo 'print "http://www.google.com>Google"' but on console output it simply displays that as raw text and not as a hyperlink (It does make the http url link clickable).

I am aware that this will work correctly in case of HTML file

Answer (score 2):

You may try [ANSI Color plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AnsiColor+Plugin) it shall auto convert it to hyperlink. I tried with java it works, you may try with Python :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. After enabling ANSIColor plugin in Jenkins, I tried a simple statement "printf '<a href=http://www.google.com>Google</a>'" and this printed out the entire raw string, instead of printing just Google with the hyperlink. I enabled the plugin from the configure page and have the color map set to default value of xterm.  Let me know if I am missing something here.

Comment: Hi, please try directly print out http://www.google.com as text without the <a>, it shall be automatically covert to hyperlink in your console.

Answer (score 1):

Install the `anything-goes-formatter`

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=60915753

Enable the Markup formatter on global configuration (security section)

http://127.0.0.1:8080/configureSecurity/

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to figure this out from Groovy code (jenkinsfile), but I knew there has to be a way as steps/plugins can do it.
In this case you need `ModelHyperlinkNote` (https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/console/ModelHyperlinkNote.html) and its static methods; so for a link to Job started you'd do:

```
final Run buildRun = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(buildJobName
  ).getBuildByNumber(runId) as Run
final String link = ModelHyperlinkNote.encodeTo(buildRun)
```

and then you can simply write that value to log and Console Log will interpret it and add widget with all relevant operations.

In addition to type-specific methods, there is general-purpose `encodeTo(String url, String text)` that allows links to other kinds of entities.